# Visual Studio 2022 don't show target frameworks to new projects

Tags: target-framework

I started using VS 2022 this week and found that when trying to create a new project in VB only .NET 5.0 and 6.0 are available as target frameworks. How do I create a new project in VB using .NET 4.8, as it is already installed as you can see in the images (I'm from Brazil, so the images show VS in Portuguese).[Actually Target Frameworks available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ela6F.jpg)[Installed resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpJxT.jpg)[Installed resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kuph6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that You are selecting the correct template, they are divided into NET and NET Framework.

For example:
[image: Console app templates]